# Precision 5540 NVMe drive benchmark a lot lower than expected

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, nvme, dell-precision

hope someone can help me figure this out. Just got Precision 5540 laptop and found that drives perform slower than my older laptop. Here are the details:

Comparing Precision 5540 and 5520 running side by side. Here is my current setup:

5520:

```
        Dell Precision 5520
        Intel Xeon CPU E3-1505M v6, 32GB of RAM
        Windows 10 Pro with all latest updates
        Samsung 960 Pro 1tb with latest firmware and latest samsung drivers
        BIOS set to use AHCI interface
```

5540:

```
        Dell Precision 5540
        Intel i9-9980HK, 16GB of RAM
        Windows 10 Pro with all latest updtaes
        Samsung 970 Pro 1tb with latest firmware and latest samsung drivers
        BIOS set to use AHCI interface
```

Even though I am comparing 2 different drives here, I did the same comparison on the exact same 256GB M.2 drive 
that came with a laptop, and got similar results - 5540 got a 20% slower score. In all other tests 5540 is scoring 
higher than 5520, but this drive issue got me puzzled.

I performed 2 different comparisons - using Samsung's Magician and AS SSD Benchmark tool. And here are the results:

**5540 Results** 
From samsung magician:

```
   Sequential Read:  3,103
   Sequential Write: 2,493
   Random Read:    193,603
   Random Write:    76,416
```

From AS SSD Benchmark 2.0: overall score 3043

**5520 Results**:

From samsung magician:

```
   Sequential Read:  2,985
   Sequential Write: 2,026
   Random Read:    297,363
   Random Write:   267,333
```

From AS SSD Benchmark 2.0: overall score 4179

You'll notice that using these different benchmark tests I am getting different results. Using Samsung's app, read and write are faster in 5540, but random is terrible

I am planning to call Dell but I am guessing there won't be much help from them. I'll probably try to contact Samsung
but based on the face that I used different drive altogether as well and still got similar results I am guessing
this is not their problem.

thanks for all the help

**Update**: I ended up talking to Samsung, and they also found it odd the results. Their response was this problem is with a driver controller- maybe just the way it's designed. Dell is replacing the laptop thinking this may be a faulty motherboard. In the mean time, I got both my laptops with the same drive Samsung 960 Pro 1tb so I can do a better side by side comparisons. What I have noticed is in 5520 the perf results are pretty consistent, where as in 5540 they are all over the place. The first time I installed OS with all the drivers on 5540 on this new drive, I got:

```
        Samsung Magician 
                Sequential (MB/s)    2.17K /   2.07K
                Random (IOPS)      250.24K / 134.28K

        AS SSD Benchmark
                Seq (MB/s)          1.38K / 1.72K
                4K (MB/s)           43.68 / 91.02
                4K-64Thrd (MB/s)    1.06K / 0.6K
                Acc Time (ms)       0.031 / 0.037
                Score                1237 / 860
                Overall score:                      2755
```

The second time I installed OS with all the drivers (I was installing 1 driver at a time to see if any one of the drivers decreases performance), I got

```
        Samsung Magician 
                Sequential (MB/s)    2.94K /   2.13K
                Random (IOPS)      272.95K /  118.9K

        AS SSD Benchmark
                Seq (MB/s)           2.16K / 1.16K
                4K (MB/s)            45.93 / 124.38 
                4K-64Thrd (MB/s)      1.1K / 1.38K
                Acc Time (ms)        0.027 / 0.029
                Score                 1365 / 1621
                Overall score:                      3641
```

Talking to Samsung they were puzzled with the inconsistency of the results. For example, sequential write is at pretty much 100% of drive capability, but Random Write is at 50%. And in the first result, sequential write is also close to 100%, but sequential read is at 60%.

But again, Samsung support did not bother to really do anything, other than advise me on contacting Dell about storage controller problems. They did indicate if the problem was with a driver or some other setting, performance I am seeing would be a lot worse than what I am seeing.

Dell has been very responsive with replacing a laptop as well as getting some very technical people involved in this problem. For now I'll wait for a new laptop

**Update**: Got a replacement laptop from Dell but the problem is still there - the biggest problem is random writes performance. This maybe a design flaw - waiting for Dell engineers to let me know what's next

Comment: There are more components that may influence throughput beside the ones above, such as motherboard, memory controller, RAM, bus and more. A complete comparison will need to compare all these, and may still not be exhaustive enough. It may happen that a computer that is faster on paper is actually slower, and I agree: It's a real bummer when it happens to you.

Comment: I understand that everything makes a difference, but when I see a 30% improvement on the old system makes me think there are some settings in windows or BIOS that I can tweak and not get into every hardware detail. I'll contact Samsung technical support on Monday and see if they have some ideas.

Comment: 7 days ago Dell published an "urgent" BIOS update (version 1.2.3) for the Precision 5540 for "Enhances the performance of the system."

Comment: Yes, I saw that and applied the BIOS - first test seemed a bit better but the next one showed the same numbers unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the reason for all the perf tests to be less than optimal was a power plan "Balanced" - the only one available to me in windows. Once I figured out how to show all other power plans and selected Ultimate the tests showed hard drive performing as advertised.

Comment: And how do you show all the other power plans?  And did you leave it at Ultimate?  Or just used that while you did the performance test?

Comment: There were ways to do this before but windows changed something the way to show all plans you can find on internet no longer work. I tried everything and from what I can tell, you can now click on the batter and select performance level. On my dell, once I installed some Dell utilities, I got High Performance power plan, but I don't know of a way to do this manually now. It's a mess and I couldn't find a good explanation of all of this